# EventReceiver not triggering with WorkflowCompleted Event In 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, event-receivers

I have created a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013, and once the workflow is completed, I need to trigger my event receiver based on the workflow status event that gets changed to workflow completed, but when I'm doing the same steps, My event receiver is not triggering after the workflow is completed, and if i  follow the same steps in designer 2010, then my event receiver is triggering. Any idea on this?

```
public override void WorkflowCompleted(SPWorkflowEventProperties properties)
{
    SPWorkflowActivationProperties activationProperties = properties.ActivationProperties;
    string worflowAssociationName = activationProperties.TemplateName;

    //compare is it for the workflow you want to work with here

}
```